# Huge font size in Google Chrome's UI

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, 20.04

[image]

As you can see, it's way bigger than Firefox's. I tried `google-chrome –high-dpi-support=1 –force-device-scale-factor=1` to no avail. Has anyone encountered this problem?

**UPDATE**

I did a fresh install and set font scaling to .94(my monitor is 1920x1080) but still the issue persists. The worst thing is, all electron apps have this huge font in context menu and menu bar. I wish I could live without them but they're essential for my work as I'm a web developer.

Interestingly, I tried PopOS, the font-scaling there works for chrome/electron but their fonts royally suck. So I'm confused why it doesn't work in Ubuntu. I thought I could go back to Ubuntu full time. Too bad.

Comment: @guiverc: Eh.. The question was submitted on April 23.

Comment: The release hadn't occurred at that time, I stopped using that *tag* about an hour before actual release/go time (ubuntu release team timetable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since nobody answered, I gave it time to research about how to get around this. The root cause is Chrome/Chromium does not respect OS font scaling. To address this, I added `--force-device-scale-factor=n` to `Exec=*` line in `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`. `n` is the value that's suitable for you, for me it's `.92`. I did this to all electron apps and now everything is all good. I'm sticking to Ubuntu after all!

Be sure to save a backup for each .desktop file you edit. Ciao!

Comment: In case you're using Plasmashell (KDE) use ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop instead. Also I did not have the issues with all Electron apps on KDE but only Chrome.